# Suspicious definition of erlang distribution in Verilog-2005 spec

Tags: verilog, math, statistics

The `$dist_erlang` function in Verilog-2005 takes an argument called `mean`. Some information about the `mean` argument of `$dist_erlang` is found in this paragraph from section 17.9.2 of the spec:

[image]

They also provide C code for how simulators ought to internally implement `$dist_erlang` (from page 320 of the spec). This code implements a [formula that can be found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Generating_Erlang-distributed_random_variates) for sampling an Erlang distribution.

```
erlangian(seed, k, mean)
long *seed, k, mean;
{
    double x, log(), a, b;
    long i;
    x = 1.0;
    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        x = x * uniform(seed, 0, 1);
    }
    a = (double)mean;
    b = (double)k;
    x = -a * log(x)/b;
    return(x);
}
```

I'm no expert on statistics, but I'm pretty sure that the multiplication by `mean` / `a` at the very end of this function is not gonna result in a distribution whose mean is `mean`. This would imply that every Erlang distribution sampled from using the equation on Wikipedia has a mean of 1, which definitely isn't true.

Am I missing something here, or is this an honest to goodness error in the Verilog spec?

Comment: This question may get better answers on math.SE instead of here. I'm not familiar with the Erlang distribution, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Anyways, after staring at it for another 10 minutes, I found my error, so I'm going to delete this question.

Comment: Before you do that, consider a self-answer. It may be useful to others.

Comment: BTW the Verilog-2005 LRM is obsolete. Please use the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). This is now section 20.15.2

Comment: AFAIK, the tools I'm using (yosys) don't support SystemVerilog. That's why I'm looking at the 2005 document.

Comment: OK, but do check the latest spec for any corrections that might have been made, next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused about this because I was confused by the parameter naming in the Verilog spec and I made a basic algebra error.

The mean can be given by `k / lambda`. The sampling formula requires `1 / lambda`, which is the same as `(k / lambda) / k`.

Taking `mean` as an argument instead of `lambda` might have been considered more user friendly.